# TeamDrive Notification Using Google admin SDK for reports having issue with owner_is_team_drive flag

Tags: push-notification, google-admin-sdk, google-cloud-sdk, google-reporting-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I'm using the documentation https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/push#making-watch-requests for creating the channel for team drive for google using google reports API. According to the document, we can make channel depending upon various filter conditions. For my purpose, I choose to use the filter "owner_is_team_drive==true". The problem with using this filter is that a channel gets created properly (I get a channel object in return) but the notification doesn't come if I perform any action.

I'm using Google Admin SDK for reports for creating the request for the channel. While looking at the logs I found that the API being used to hit the request is https://www.googleapis.com/admin/reports/v1/activity/users/all/applications/drive?filters=owner_is_team_drive%3D%3Dtrue

PS: I tried using other filters(like "doc_type==team_drive") and also the API without filters, I get the notification properly.

Comment: Could you please provide the logs you received?

Comment: The logs you mean the response while creating the channels?